# How to avoid continuous headers during a loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, header

I am trying to extract information from multiple files (4 files in the current example) using R. Each file creates a row. I managed to get 4 rows in the final data frame. However, each time I get headers as well. Can you help me know what can I do to avoid getting continuous headers, and only keep the first one?

Here is my code, along with the current output:

```
AR.MOD.files <- list.files(pattern = "AR.MOD")
    for (fileName in AR.MOD.files) {
    AR.MOD <- read.table(fileName, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
    AR.MOD.subset1 <- AR.MOD[c(1), 3:4]
    names(AR.MOD.subset1) <- c("Col1", "Col2")
    AR.MOD.subset2 <- AR.MOD[c(3), 3:8]
    names(AR.MOD.subset2) <- c("Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7", "Col8")
    AR.MOD.final <- merge(AR.MOD.subset1, AR.MOD.subset2)
    ID <- basename(fileName)
    AR.MOD.final <- merge (ID, AR.MOD.final)
    colnames(AR.MOD.final)[colnames(AR.MOD.final)=="x"] <- "ID"
    print(AR.MOD.final)}

             ID       Col1     Col2   Col3    Col4 Col5  Col6 Col7  Col8
1 File1.MOD 21-12-2017 11:25:37 590,30 1045,54 2,23 43,33 0,63 44,00
             ID       Col1    Col2   Col3    Col4 Col5  Col6 Col7  Col8
1 File2.MOD 21-12-2017 8:40:35 686,12 1240,13 1,89 49,64 0,64 44,00
             ID      Col1    Col2   Col3    Col4 Col5  Col6 Col7  Col8
1 File3.MOD 12-1-2018 8:44:49 665,15 1260,73 1,64 52,03 0,60 51,00
             ID       Col1     Col2   Col3   Col4 Col5  Col6 Col7  Col8
1 File4.MOD 21-12-2017 10:22:01 572,28 936,55 2,73 45,33 0,65 39,00
```

Apologies if this has already been asked before, but I could not figure it out even after looking for the answer.
Thanking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote : *"I managed to get 4 rows in the final data frame."*
However, actually it is not a total dataframe, you are printing every single row separately. If you are okey with printing once an entire output, adding `if` statement maybe a solution as below.

```
    for (fileName in AR.MOD.files) {

        AR.MOD <- read.table(fileName, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
        AR.MOD.subset1 <- AR.MOD[c(1), 3:4]
        names(AR.MOD.subset1) <- c("Col1", "Col2")
        AR.MOD.subset2 <- AR.MOD[c(3), 3:8]
        names(AR.MOD.subset2) <- c("Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7", "Col8")
        AR.MOD.final <- merge(AR.MOD.subset1, AR.MOD.subset2)
        ID <- basename(fileName)
        AR.MOD.final <- merge (ID, AR.MOD.final)
        colnames(AR.MOD.final)[colnames(AR.MOD.final)=="x"] <- "ID"

         #print(AR.MOD.final)


        if(match(fileName,AR.MOD.files)==1){

            output <- AR.MOD.final

        }else{

            output <- rbind(output,AR.MOD.final)
        }


     }

   print(output)
```